# MongoDB How to filter db.adminCommand output

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

does anybody know how to filter mongodb db.adminCommand output? Because if I run this command `db.adminCommand({ "currentOp": true, "op" : "query", "planSummary": "COLLSCAN" })` I get a huge JSON output but I'm only interested in some fields ( like secs_running, op, command, $db)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the filters straight to the command object like the following:

```js
var commandObj = {
        "currentOp" : 1,
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "$or" : [
                {
                        "op" : {
                                "$in" : [
                                        "insert",
                                        "update",
                                        "remove"
                                ]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "command.findandmodify" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                        }
                }
        ]
};

db.adminCommand(commandObj);
```

You can see some filter examples on the MongoDB docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/#examples

Just re-read your question and I think you might of meant just projecting fields back from the database that you care about? if that's the case you can just execute a map on top of the current results so you only see what you care about?

```js
db.adminCommand(commandObj).inprog.map(x => x.opid};
```